# How to play the Totem of a Barbarian

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, barbarian

I understand that the Totem gives the Barbarian some abilities during level progression. But I do not completely understand what exactly the Totem is. Let us say I have the Bear Totem

- Do I have a wooden bear with me that I pray to?
- Do I have a real bear with me?
- Do I have nothing with me and just some kind of spirit inside of me?

Comment: Have you fully read through the Path of the Totem Warrior description in the PHB?

Comment: I did read only the first level description not through to the 3rd. "The barbarian accepts a sprit animal as guide, protector and inspiration" is a bit vague for me and I cannot grasp it. Is this a spirit I can talk to in my head or is it rather a physical attribute that I have intherited

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### A spiritual guide, a physical totem, and possibly a change of appearance.

The subclass introduction states:

> The Path of the Totem Warrior is a spiritual journey, as **the barbarian accepts a spirit animal as guide, protector, and inspiration.** In battle, your totem spirit fills you with supernatural might, adding magical fuel to your barbarian rage.

Totem Spirit, the 3rd level feature, states:

> At 3rd level, when you adopt this path, you choose a totem spirit and gain its feature. **You must make or acquire a physical totem object — an amulet or similar adornment — that incorporates fur or feathers, claws, teeth, or bones of the totem animal.** At your option, you also gain minor physical attributes that are reminiscent of your totem spirit. For example, if you have a bear totem spirit, you might be unusually hairy and thick-skinned, or if your totem is the eagle, your eyes turn bright yellow.

So these are the things that the rules "require" in a strict sense. How you choose to roleplay your relationship with the totem spirit is really up to you. There is obviously no gameplay balance associated with how you choose to do that, so even having a physical totem as the description says you "must" isn't really even necessary.

The feature description of Totem Spirit even encourages you to take some liberty with how you integrate the totem spirit into your character's story:

> Your totem animal might be an animal related to those listed here but more appropriate to your homeland. For example, you could choose a hawk or vulture in place of an eagle.

Comment: The 'spirit animal' is the totem, and the 3rd level feature refers to a 'totem **object**'... might be a good distinction to highlight as the original text is inconsistent (one sentence says 'spirit animal' the next says ' totem spirit').

Comment: Very few DMs or players are as strict with having to have a totem or symbol as this answer makes it seem. The game is moving away from "book says must" to "RP it your way" and I think this answer would benefit from that kind of explanation.

Answer (score 6):

#### How you play this is up to you

In most cases I've experienced, people just pick the path and never even bother to describe in detail how they make or aquire their totem, nevermind do they describe how they are praying to their spirit animal.

But this differs from table to table. If you are more into imagining how the character would behave and role-playing the character, and less into just combat and exploration, you might have lots of fun praying to your spirit animal.

The rules merely demand that

> At 3rd level, when you adopt this path, you choose a totem spirit and gain its feature. You must **make or acquire a physical totem object** — an amulet or similar adornment — t**hat incorporates fur or feathers, claws, teeth, or bones of the totem animal**. At your option, you also gain minor physical attributes that are reminiscent of your totem spirit. For example, if you have a bear totem spirit, you might be unusually hairy and thick-skinned, or if your totem is the eagle, your eyes turn bright yellow.

- you would not have a just "wooden bear" that you pray to, because the totem "incorporates fur or feathers, claws, teeth, or bones of the totem animal", so even if statuette of a bear made from wood, it would need to incroporate bear fur, teeth, claws or bones.
- you do not need to have a real bear with you
- you may not even need to carry the totem with you. The rules do not mention that you need to have the totem on your person as part of your equipment, only that you "make or acquire" it; many adventurers do not have a permanent home, so it would be likely you carry it around, but if you had a shrine or hut somewhere, it might be possible to deposit it there

The totem does represent your connection with your *spirit animal*, so what you really would pray to, what you really are connected to, and what you receive your powers and potential physical similarity from is that spirit animal. The totem object is just an effigy representing it.

> The Path of the Totem Warrior is a spiritual journey, as **the barbarian accepts a spirit animal as guide, protector, and inspiration**.

Answer (score 1):

### The totem, or your link to a bear doesn't really matter in practise

Fluff wise, the barbarian was written as a tribal warrior, with some kind of connection to shamanistic rituals and the spirits of animals, or their ancestors etc.

A few of the barbarian rules talk about this, saying things like

> You must make or acquire a physical totem object

However the word **must** in itself is very against the spirit of D&D, and in recent times the writers (and players) have moved away from this prescribed style of play.

I have seen somewhere in an official source (if anyone can source it for me that would be great) that you can even reflavour it to be a hippo, or dinosaur, or something else that says "I am tough because".

I wouldn't worry about what you **should** have, and instead concentrate on what you feel your character **would** have, if they even have anything at all. You could stick to having a physical totem, you could talk to a spirit (ask your DM for this because you might be giving them work voicing a spirit), you could even have been bitten by a radioactive bear escaped from a secret lab and now have inherited bear powers.

What matters isn't the rule, it is the character.

Comment: I strongly disagree. The totem object acts as a balancing factor similar to a wizard's spellbook or any caster's focus/spell component pouch.

Comment: @nick012000 what lol? You balance around a free object with no written rules?

Comment: It has written rules: you need it to use your totem powers - and it arguably does have a listed cost, under the "druidic focus" equipment list.